# Any way to see Debug output without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++, debugging

Using MFC's TRACE macro or OutputDebugString from the Windows API, you can write to the output window of Visual Studio. Is there any way to see this output on a system where you don't have Visual Studio installed, and don't want to install it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Debugview from Sysinternals/Microsoft

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it clearly states the source of the product.

Comment: You want to know about sysinternals, there are a number of utilities there that I find indispensable. The most critical is ProcessExplorer, and DebugView is a close second.

Answer (score 9):

You can capture the output from OutputDebugString with [DebugView for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx):

> DebugView is an application that lets
>   you monitor debug output on your local
>   system, or any computer on the network
>   that you can reach via TCP/IP. It is
>   capable of displaying both kernel-mode
>   and Win32 debug output, so you don't
>   need a debugger to catch the debug
>   output your applications or device
>   drivers generate, nor do you need to
>   modify your applications or drivers to
>   use non-standard debug output APIs.